# Empty CSV after Scrapy Crawl

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I keep on getting an empty CSV file after running my code. I suspect it might be the XPaths but I really don't know what I'm doing. There aren't any errors reported in the terminal output. I'm trying to get info from various Craigslist [pages](http://pittsburgh.craigslist.org//pts/5539970769.html).

```
 from scrapy.spiders import Spider
 from scrapy.selector import Selector
 from craigslist_probe.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(Spider):
 name = "why"

 allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]

 f = open("urls.txt")
 start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
 f.close()

 def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.selector.xpath("/section[@id='pagecontainer']")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item["img"] = titles.xpath("./div[@class='tray']").extract()
        item["body"] = titles.xpath("./section[@id='postingbody']/text()").extract()
        item["itemID"] = titles.xpath(".//div[@class='postinginfos']/p[@class='postinginfo']").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: have you checked if the item fields are being populated? using some `print` or logs on them?

Comment: You can try out your xpaths using `scrapy shell` or using a tool like Firebug for Firefox. These will let you run an xpath search and see the returned values. Very handy. On a style note, `for titles in titles:` isn't pretty, `for title in titles:` would be better. Python doesn't seem to care though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your XPath doesn't correspond to the HTML structure of the page. Notice that single slash (`/`) infers *direct child*, so, for example, `/section` would only work if the root element of the page is `<section>` element, which hardly ever be the case. Try using `//` all over :

```
def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.selector.xpath("//section[@id='pagecontainer']")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item["img"] = titles.xpath(".//div[@class='tray']").extract()
        item["body"] = titles.xpath(".//section[@id='postingbody']/text()").extract()
        item["itemID"] = titles.xpath(".//div[@class='postinginfos']/p[@class='postinginfo']").extract()
        items.append(item)
```